# Parsing "12/25/35" to a date using InvariantCulture (2-digit year)

Tags: .net, windows, datetime, locale, regional-settings

When I use the `InvariantCulture` to parse a string, with both:

```cs
var christ1 = DateTime.Parse("12/25/35", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and:

```cs
var christ2 = DateTime.ParseExact("12/25/35", "MM/dd/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

the result depends on what computer the application runs on. On one machine I get the equivalent of:

> December 25, **20**35

while on another machine I get a date one century earlier, that is:

> December 25, **19**35

What is going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The so-called invariant culture is not so invariant in this case. It depends on both your OS version and the current user's regional settings in the OS.

In .NET terms, the property of interest is `TwoDigitYearMax` on the calendar, so inspect `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax` or `(new GregorianCalendar()).TwoDigitYearMax`. [Documentation of `GregorianCalendar.TwoDigitYearMax` override](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar.twodigityearmax).

On a Windows 10 version 1809 ("October 2018 Update", "Redstone 5") machine where the user has not changed the regional settings (more on that below), the property `TwoDigitYearMax` is `2029`, and as a consequence you get December 25, **19**35.

But on Windows 10 version 1903 ("May 2019 Update", "19H1"), the same property returns `2049`, and therefore your result is December 25, **20**35.

However, the value depends not only on the Windows version. Also what the user inputs in regional settings, matters. So that is not really "invariant".

You can change the cutoff year in the Control Panel by:

1. Click **Start**, click "gear" icon on the left (Settings), and click **Time & Language**.
2. Click **Region** on the left.
3. Under **Related settings**, click **Additional date, time, & regional settings**.
4. (You are in Control Panel.) Click **Region**.
5. (In new **Region** window.) Click button **Additional settings...** near bottom of   page, and in new window click **Date** tab.
6. In the **Calendar** group, adjust **When a two-digit year is entered, interpret it as a year between**.

In older Windows flavors, it may be (pasted from `microsoft.com`):

1. Click **Start**, point to **Settings**, and then click **Control Panel**.
2. Double-click the **Regional Settings** icon.
3. Click the **Date** tab.
4. In the **When a two digit year is entered, interpret a year between** box, type the cutoff year that you want, and then click **OK**.

Or you can use Windows Registry directly, go to key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\Calendars\TwoDigitYearMax`, and for every relevant "value" in that key, keep the *name* component unchanged and edit the *data* component of the value to (the usual decimal string representation of) the cutoff year you desire. If the user has never changed this setting from the Control Panel, the two innermost keys (`Calendars\TwoDigitYearMax`) do not exist yet. Usual warnings about mingling with the registry apply.

Once you changed the year in the Control Panel, every .NET process that is *started* after you made these changes, will reflect your choice in the `TwoDigitYearMax` property reached through `InvarantCulture`!

So if you want consistent behavior across OS versions and user preferences, I think you cannot use `InvariantCulture`. Instead, something like this could work:

```cs
var tmp = (CultureInfo)(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone());
tmp.DateTimeFormat.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 2039; // any cutoff you need
 // incorrect: tmp.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 2039
var newInvariantCulture = CultureInfo.ReadOnly(tmp);
```

then use that `newInvariantCulture` instance whenever you parse dates with 2-digit years (you can put it in some `static readonly` field).

**WARNING:** Each `CultureInfo x` carries two distinct `Calendar`s that *may* have different 2-digit year max, namely:

```cs
x.DateTimeFormat.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax
  !=
x.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax
```

Comment: Yep. Relying on the particular machine (and its particular regional settings) to get it right is dangerous. Better to force the conversion to work the same way across all servers, essentially ignoring all regional settings.

Comment: @DavidRTribble It is a common belief that when you use `CultureInfo.InvariantInfo`, then you are safe. But in this case regional settings (and Windows version) do affect the result, even with "invariant info" passed.